# Force WCF to use NetDataContractSerializer\DataContractSerializer

Tags: wcf, serialization

How can I tell a certain WCF Service to use DataContractSerializer or NetDataContractSerializer?

Suppose I succeed, will the proxy generated automatically identify it and use the correct one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` is used by default. On the service side you can control used serializers with behaviors. By default you have available `DataContractFormat` and `XmlSerializerFormat` attributes for this. These attributes can be applied on service contract, service implementation or on operations. On client side svcutil will use data contract serialization if types description are serializable by `DataContractSerializer` otherwise it will use `XmlSerializer`.

`NetDataContractSerializer` doesn't have behaviour prepared - [you must create it yourselves](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/04/21/22284.aspx). It is also not recognized by clients because when you use `NetDataContractSerializer` you will share assemblies with types (data contracts, service contracts) with client so you can share behaviour as well and mark service contract with that behaviour directly.

Comment: The link is sadly broken